# Quote inside the braces replaced with @ and throws parse error

Tags: syntax-error, octave, parse-error

When I run the code from editor window, though the command is `load('ex4data1.mat')`, it throws error and says parse error at `load(@ex4data1.mat@)`. How to resolve this?

Left side of the screen says "syntax error" and the right side of the screen shows the editor with correct code without "syntax error":

[image]

Comment: Try using double quotes, as per the documentation.  https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/load.html

Comment: is this code you typed youself? Or did you copy it from somewhere? Sometimes code copy-pasted from websites looks legitimate, but uses unicode symbols that _look_ like a quote but is actually something else. Which then the octave terminal fails to represent properly (and obviouly fails to interpret properly too).